# how can i set the current location into a literal current location using geolocation of google maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

[Place Autocomplete and Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions)

Comment: Are you trying to get the coordinates of the location using the Geolocation API?

Answer (score 0):

> Use FusedLocationProvideClient

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient